# ASP.NET Application - Architecture and Class Diagrams

Tags: asp.net, architecture, class, diagrams

I am new to ASP.NET Development.

Could anyone please refer a document/tutorial/link which gives a sample code, architecture, class and sequence diagrams for 3 / 4 / n tier based simple ASP.NET application/example?

It would be of great help to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of techniques / tool and various ways to do what you asked with .Net so I will give you some links for various tools:

N-Tier with:

ASP.Net 2.0

http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2006/08/13/3_2D00_tier-Architecture-wtih-ASP.NET-2.0.aspx

ASP.Net 3.5

http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=476

LINQ 2 SQL

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/02/28/building-an-n-layer-asp-net-application-with-linq-lambdas-and-stored-procedures.aspx

Dynamic Data

http://weblogs.asp.net/craigshoemaker/archive/2008/07/01/6-steps-to-n-tier-asp-net-dynamic-data.aspx

MVC

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnetmvc_bugtracker_v4.aspx

There is a lot of examples out there.  Don't take the one's I have given you as the only one's but as a start for you. :-)

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

I made this sketch recently when explaining the difference between a typical classic Microsoft .ASP/SQL Server website architecture, and one that incorporates the newer Microsoft ASP.NET technology.

The box labeled “Front” at the top of the diagram represents a public website. Could be any size, large or small.
The “can” at the bottom represents a SQL Server database that is behind the scenes. The website user really doesn’t know or care that it is there, holding all the data for the website.
The middle area represents what can be done with ASP.NET technology. The boxes represent little “engines” of code that do specific things. One might process a credit card. One might add an item to a shopping cart. Another might list items on a page with a thumbnail image next to them. The list is endless.
The point here is that with ASP.NET, all these “engines” can be ready at anytime for use by themselves, or in combination with other “engines” to perform website tasks, and features. This lessens the amount of special code that needs to be placed inside the actual web pages represented by the top box. It is a far more efficient, and much faster technology, especially the more complex and complicated a website may be.

Just thought you might like to know that.

Comment: You don't seem to have linked the image you want to use to explain?

Answer (score 0):

This may be the best collection you will find...
http://www.asp.net/get-started/

Answer (score 0):

Look at [sharpdevelop](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/)
It provides a solid foundation for creating asp.net mvc apps using best practices.
The project even provides Visual Studio templates.

Answer (score -1):

Do yourself a favour and start with [ASP.NET MVC](http://asp.net/mvc) and leave Webforms behind. Rob's [Storefront tutorial](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront) is a great 3 tier example and the videos make it very easy to learn.